# Parameter not recognized in a Jenkinsfile method

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am doing a method call :

```
notifyGerrit('Success')
```

and the method definition is

```
def notifyGerrit(String msg) { 
    sh ''' 
       ssh -i ${JENKINS_PUB_KEY} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \ 
           -p 12345 gerrit.abc.com gerrit review \ 
              ${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER},${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER} \ 
           --label ${msg} \ -m "'Successful: ${BUILD_URL}'" 
      ''' 
}
```

When this gets executed, the `--label` gets empty value

```
+ ssh -i **** -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 12345 gerrit.abc.com gerrit review 4134,1 --label -m ''\'' Successful: https://abc.gerrit.com/'\''' fatal: Label vote missing '=': -m
```

I tried using 
`{msg}`
`msg`
`$msg`
`${msg}`
but none of these work. How do I get the value of the parameter msg inside the block of code. Note that other variables like `${BUILD_URL}` etc coming from the environment works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interpolate `$msg` variable with the string you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Something like this:

```
def notifyGerrit(String msg) { 
    sh """ 
       ssh -i ${JENKINS_PUB_KEY} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \ 
           -p 12345 gerrit.abc.com gerrit review \ 
              ${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER},${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER} \ 
           --label ${msg} \ 
           -m \\"'Successful: ${BUILD_URL}'\\" 
      """ 
}
```